# Responsive jcarousel doesn't resize images

Tags: javascript

Im using the jcarousel module and its responsive setting:

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/carousel/

Below you can see screenshots of how it works. When I resize the browser and the final image doenst fit it is then hidden.

[image]

[image]

This is working however the original jQuery plug in also resizes the remaining images so they take up the full available width:

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/

How can I get my Drupal site to behave the same way? The only solution I can think of is pretty hacky. I could run javascript on page load and window resize which measured the images and the container, and then resized the images to take up the full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not an official jcarousel release that uses v0.3.x you have limited options if you want to use jCarousel.

There is a [jCarousel 7.x-3.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/2349709) version being worked on that will use jCarousel 0.3.x but it is in development still and should only be used for testing purposes. With some good testing, I would imagine that you could use this version without much worry.

Personally, I would not use the development version or try to hack v0.3.x into the current release.  I ran into this issue a while back and ended up using [OwlCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel).  This module offers very similar functionality and seems a bit ahead of jCarousel as far as responsive settings go.  If you're not locked into using jCarousel, I'd give OwlCarousel a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think [JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) still uses 0.2.x version of the JCarousel library and the [example](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/) you're refering uses version 0.3.3 of the library which brings wider responsive support. Since 0.2.x and 0.3.x are not compatible as one can read here https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel, I think it will be difficult to achieve the features of the 0.3.x library in the drupal module. Look at the roadmap on https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel